# How to go back to the previous controller in one click after observing several controllers of the same type on iOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigation, mvvmcross, parentviewcontroller

We are using *MvvmCross 4.4.0* on the our *iOS* project and I faced the following problem:

- I need to implement **"Item"** page with reference to the other
  **"Item"** page;
- I need an instant back navigation from any **"Item"** page to the previous controller (**"Catalogue"** controller).

Diagram:

Catalogue --ConcreteItem--> Item1 --MoreItems--> Item2 --MoreItems-->

Item3 --BackNavButton--> Catalogue.

I am doing the following thing in the Custom ViewPresenter:

```
                var topViewController = ParentRootViewController.TopViewController;
                ParentRootViewController.PushViewController(currentViewController, needAnimation);

                if (topViewController.GetType() == currentView.GetType()
                    && /*Logic to determine if its correct view types*/)
                {
                    topViewController.RemoveFromParentViewController();
                    topViewController.Dispose();
                }
```

And actually it works until I didn't return to the **"Catalogue"** page. 
The problem is that I need to click back button so many times I had clicked **"More"** button on **"Item"** page. Also if we use custom back button with such code in both **"Catalogue"** and **"Item"** pages:

```
  if (NavigationController?.NavigationBar?.BackItem != null)
        {
             var backbutton = new UIBarButtonItem(" ",
                                                 UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
                                                 (sender, e) => { NavigationController?.PopViewController(true); })
            {
                Image = UIImage.FromBundle("BackButtonImage")
            };

            NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = backbutton;
        }
```

then app crashes when clicking **"Back"** NavButton on **"Catalogue"** page with  in lambda

```
(sender, e) => { NavigationController?.PopViewController(true);
```

The disposed object **ItemPageViewController**.

The question is : How to correctly implement "SingleTop" page in MvvmCross?

Or

How to fix this problem?

P.S.: If from MvxPresenter remove line

```
topViewController.Dispose();
```

then in custom lambda would throw NullReferenceException.

P.P.S.: I believe it the problem that I don't remove controller from navigation stack. I have tried to remove controllers in Custom View Presenter, but, firstly, it is null there sometimes, and even with null check nothing helped.

Comment: is Catalogue  the starting point of your app ?

Comment: @Pilatus, No, it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UINavigationController` has a function `PopToViewController(UIViewController viewController, bool animated);`

Instead of removing every `ViewController` when the views are of the same type, you could pop to the `ViewController` Catalogue when the backbutton is pressed.

`UINavigationController` has a property `ViewControllers` that we can use to find `CatalogueViewController`.

Since you're using `MvvmCross` we'll check for the `ViewModel` type.

```
var catalogueController = NavigationController.ViewControllers.First(c => 
    ((IMvxIosView)c).ViewModel.GetType() == typeof(CatalogueViewModel));
```

Now you can use the function `PopToViewController` to close all the views untill `CatalogueController`

```
CurrentNavigationController.PopToViewController(catalogueController, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this and it worked. The only drawback is that I had do to use custom back button and specify the concrete type of parent controller which are dependencies. Bu I really wanted to have a generic solution.

Comment: You could create an interface, implement it on the `ViewModel` and search for `ViewModel` that implements that interface and pop to that `ViewController`. Then this solution would be more generic.